# VPN connection successfully established, but IP address does not change

Tags: 12.04, vpn, openvpn

I have set up an OpenVPN connection via the network manager on Ubuntu 12.04 following these instructions:

https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/#ubuntu_openvpn_installer

Initially I could not access any websites when connecting to the VPN network.

I then ticked the box for 'Use this connection only for resources on its network' under IPv4 Settings, Routes.

After ticking the box everything seemed to work. I could connect to the VPN network and open websites.

I only coincidentally noticed though, that although the network manager tells me that I have successfully connected to the VPN network, my IP address does not change.

I then looked into the Private Internet Access configuration files downloaded from the link above and found the port number 1194, which I opened using the firewall configuration tool Firewall.

I also unticked the box 'Use this connection only for resources on its network' and connected to the VPN network. I can do Google searches and access one or two random websites, but then I get a 'connection failed' from the browser.

It seems to connect to the VPN network successfully though. The IP address changes according to the host I am using.

I would be really great full for some tips. I tried to fix this problem for some time but have not been successful in my attempt.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the problem by adding OpenDNS servers (208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220) under IPv4 Settings, Automatic (VPN) addresses only. I also reticked the 'Use this connection only for resources on its network' box. Now it's working. IP address is changing.

Thanks